# CodeIgniter + QuickAuth + One User, only One Session

Tags: session, codeigniter

this may be a easy question, but I really need a light to go on.

I have this huge PHP system in codeigniter, and I'm using the library Quick Auth, and I need let users log on only at one computer/browser at a given time. So if Jake logs on In PC1, then Jakes tries to log on in PC2, PC1 session get invalidated and closed.

I was trying to manually search in the ci_sessions database table to try to eliminate the other user session, but seems like too pain. I want to know if there's one simple solution, I have no problem extending session, but I need more like an advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to modify either the table indexes or session library code to limit one user to a single session.  This can be done by:

- Adding a unique index for the username (or ID) and the cookie/session ID
- Modifying the library code to `INSERT OR REPLACE` based on the user/cookie